# Unable to Read Data (for textfield)

Tags: swift, textfield

I am trying to store the value of the textfield String to Firebase but the debugger says "unable to read data (String)." Here is my code.

```
@IBAction func btnSelect(_ sender: Any) {
    var Description: String = TextField.text ?? ""
}
```

Comment: Use lowercase for variable names.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. I suggest you post a relevant screenshot from Xcode showing the issue in the debugger.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try declaring Description first outside of viewDidLoad(), then initialize it inside the function btnSelect()

I created an example without using the storyBoard and it is working

```
let TextField : UITextField = {
    let txt = UITextField()
    txt.text = "Hello World"
    return txt
}()

var Description: String?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    btnSelect()
}

func btnSelect() {
    Description = TextField.text
    print(Description)
}
```

If this does not work for you, it must be something to do with either how you are initializing TextField or something with your storyBoard.

Comment: so var betDescription: String in viewDidLoad() and var betDescription = betTextField.text ?? "" in btnSelect?

Comment: Thank you! It is giving me a String for "value" in debugger for the view controller Description is in. However when I use ViewController.Description ?? "" in another view controller I get nil. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You're welcome! :)   To get the value from another viewController, you have a few options.  One is using UserDefaults.  To set the data, use:  UserDefaults.standard.set(Description, forKey: "Description").     And to get the data from the next view controller, use this line: 
        UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Description")